# Remove rows containing duplicate elements

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates, vectorization

I have this example matrix:

```
1 2 4 5 1 3
2 3 5 6 3 4
1 2 3 4 5 6
3 2 4 6 1 5
...
```

I need to delete each row that contains duplicate elements. In this example I have to delete the first and second rows. 
I know how to do this in a `for`-loop, but I don't want to use a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `A` as the input matrix, you could do -

```
A(all(diff(sort(A,2),[],2),2),:)
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     2     4     5     1     3
     2     3     5     6     3     4
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     3     2     4     6     1     5
>> A(all(diff(sort(A,2),[],2),2),:)
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     3     2     4     6     1     5
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind some [`bsxFUN`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
A(~any(sum(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(A,[1 3 2])),2)>1,3),:)
```

Comment: I'm testing first solution, in case of a very big (20*10^6 by 12) matrix is a little bit slow, do you know an other solution? The second solution (bsxFUN) is very very slow. thanks!

Comment: @PietroZ. I would blame the number of elements being so huge :) Did you mean slower in comparison to some for-loop implementation that you had before?